# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar un radio button para que solo me permita ingresar números enteros y si cambio de opción me permita ingresar decimales?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
` <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">

              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i></span>
              <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nombreTarea" name="nombreTarea" placeholder="Ingresar Nombre o Descripcion de Tareas" required></textarea>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="radioButton"><br>
            <p><b>FORMATO DE DATO: <br>
 
            </b></p>
          <tr><input type="radio" class="radio" name="operacion" target="1" value="numerico" ><b>NUMERICO</b></input>
          <tr><input type="radio" class="radio" name="operacion" target="2" value="porcentual"><b>PORCENTUAL</b></input> 
          </div>
          
          <center><b>Tareas Programadas</b></center><br>
          <section class="target_box">
         
          <div class="box one" id="div1" class="target">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
              <center>
                <p>Ene</p>
              </center>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevaene_e" name="nuevaene_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
              <center>
                <p>Feb</p>
              </center>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevofeb_e" name="nuevofeb_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
              <center>
                <p>Mar</p>
              </center>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevamar_e" name="nuevamar_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>Abr</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevoabr_e" name="nuevoabr_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>May</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevamay_e" name="nuevamay_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>Jun</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevojun_e" name="nuevojun_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>Jul</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevajul_e" name="nuevajul_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>Ago</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevoago_e" name="nuevoago_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>Sep</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevasep_e" name="nuevasep_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>Oct</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevooct_e" name="nuevooct_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>Nov</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevonov_e" name="nuevonov_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <center>
                    <p>Dic</p>
                  </center>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nuevodic_e" name="nuevodic_e" value="0" min="0" max="100" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>`
```

[![Grupo de Radio buttons que limitan el tipo de dato][1]][1]

lo que pretendo es que los radio buttons solo me permitan que en los inputs me acepten datos numéricos enteros sin comas ni puntos y en porcentual me permita ingresar comas decimales,
todos los inputs tienen diferente id ya que en la base de datos se guardan en columnas diferentes al momento de ingresar un dato diferente al seleccionado en el radio button que este se cambie automáticamente o me salga un mensaje de alerta que el dato no es del tipo seleccionado.[![validación][2]][2]
este es el codigo de la validacion para guardar la tarea y que me aparezcan mensajes si no están llenados los campos de arriba o los radio buttons de las operaciones que son numérico y porcentual.

````
```
````

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#guardarTarea').click(function() {

```
  var id_operacion = $(this).attr("idOperacion");
  var mensaje = document.getElementById("alerta");

  nom_tar = $('#nombreTarea').val();
  if (nom_tar == "") {
    mensaje.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger"> <a href="" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" > &times; </a> Insertar una descripcion a la Tarea </div>';
    $('#nombreTarea').focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    mensaje.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if(!document.querySelector('input[name="operacion"]:checked')) {
  mensaje.innerHTML = '<div class= "alert alert-danger"> <a href="" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"> &times; </a> Elija un formato de Dato</div>';
  hasError = false;
  return false;
  }
  else{
    mensaje.innerHTML="";
  }}
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFwLE.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLdYV.png
```

Comment: Deberías mostrar algo del código que hiciste o lo que investigaste.

Comment: Una recomendación, deberías escribir el código en la pregunta, las imágenes son complementarias a la formulación de la pregunta, imagina lo tedioso que es para los que queramos ayudarte, que tengamos que abrir tu imagen y empezar a transcribir linea por linea para poder tener tu código base y trabajar en él.

Comment: disculpa me pierdo un poco de como formular la pregunta :(

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask te dejo esta sección que te ayudara a formular una buena pregunta para que justamente ayude a que podamos ayudarte, valga la redundancia.

Answer (score 0):

Haces onchange en cada input radio y le modificas el `pattern` de los inputs usando [regex](https://regexr.com)

```html
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9\/]+">
```

[Código de ejemplo](https://zhenglinlei.github.io/paste-code/#XQAAAQDPAQAAAAAAAAAtiIAkw7b7HPz+MoSYm4oioWmJrVbS6QSdR8XZg1x2y1Zg7S9T2mI257NjYvFbA89Zh2h81Wbpt7GiTpof3koaBaD4XVxCeW3qh6ilyORo45PyN0vhA88vhWWd9fGznU18EsqeKDqHzR6kxwtoF0r+X8xVXGaAgx+GOGb8h0rZ5V6E/gKLRHcWiK1Gg+Bj8b0BP+xgx/35PO09EWT1STSX4doDuFOC0BP5ZXHKTI+UoGIwPTgGAMbVvh4YSDPIUsD84zpvgz9ogAmCk36Yh969Qk/OfiSYkxCwZNTVumI1IZxJR0juC3qVmemhSg3/2hpOAA==)